# Debug / Execute Discourse plugin from command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, discourse

I'm programming a new plugin in discourse and need to output some information to know if I'm in the right way.

There is some way (With rake or something) to manually run the plugin and see what happen?

Sidekiq don't show any output...

Thanks!

**Edit 1**
The plugin force some users to watch categories... And run each 1 hour. I can see it in Sidekiq.

```
module ::WatchCategory

  def self.watch_category!
    //The logic, foreach, etc...
  end
end

after_initialize do
  module ::WatchCategory
    class WatchCategoryJob < ::Jobs::Scheduled
      every 1.hours

      def execute(args)
        WatchCategory.watch_category!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please provide some code or more info. What is this plugin? How do you integrate it with discourse?

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used discourse but it looks like a rails app so you should be able to start rails console via rails c. Then you should be able to run your code like 'WatchCategory.watch_category!'

Comment: Thanks! That help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is dial it back to a minute for testing purposes and drop a `puts 'Hello World'` statement in there.

Then all you need to do is start a Rails console and do: `::WatchCategory.watch_category!`

You should see the `Hello World` every minute (or however long you dial it back to)